# Submitting form via Ajax - FormData and serialize not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, serialization, form-data

Im trying to submit a form with data through ajax, but my form data array is always empty. Can u help me. I tried both methods serialize and FormData, but both comming with a empty array as response.

Jquery code:

```
    $("#inschrijvencursus").submit(function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        var fd = $("#inschrijvencursus").serialize();
                        // var fd = new FormData(this);
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "/wp-content/themes/tweb/page-cursistenopgeven.php",
                            data: fd,
                            // cache: false,
                            // processData: false,
                            // contentType: false,
                            type: 'POST',
                            success: function (data) {
                                console.log(data);
                                $('#formdata').html(data);
                            }  
                        });
```

Form:

```
<form method="post" id="inschrijvencursus">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="company-name">Bedrijfsnaam</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="company" placeholder="Bedrijfsnaam">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Naam</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Naam">
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox1" value="option1">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox1">Man</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="inlineCheckbox2" value="option2">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineCheckbox2">Vrouw</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Telefoonnummer</label>
        <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="telephone" placeholder="Telefoonnummer">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Email</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleTextarea">Opmerkingen</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" id="opmerkingen" rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" id="cursussubmit" class="nexttab"></button>
</form>
```

Comment: The HTML output from the PHP and the JS looks fine. Have you debugged the PHP to see what it receives?

Comment: On the php page im doing a print_r($_POST); this outputs that the array is empty. @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: I just found out that when i console.log(fd) after the serialize function it's empty so fd is not getting the data from the form how is that possible @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: Do you have multiple elements on the page with the same `inschrijvencursus` id?

Answer (score 0):

Just found the solution. When you are using the serialize function the input elements in your form need a name="yourname"  to send with jquery to work.